# Jsoup кодировка � Webview

Tags: android, html, jsoup

Получаю � вместо Русского текста. В чем может быть проблема в https://try.jsoup.org/ тоже самое.
Начало html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
```

конец

```
</table>


<!-- RedHelper -->
<script id="rhlpscrtg" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="async" 
    src="https://web.redhelper.ru/service/main.js">
</script> 
<!--/Redhelper -->



</body>
</html>
```

Страница заканчиваете я на php/
Получаю Webview так -  `myWeb.loadData(text, "text/html", "CP1251");` ставил разные кодировки

Проблема в webview текст выводит нормально

Comment: возможно, проблемы с кодировкой на самом сервере

Comment: да может, но сейчас проверил как на текствью выводи там все нормально с отображается *Проблема в webview текст выводит нормально - добавил

Comment: Нашел ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961589/, сорян нужно было писать loadData(text, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

Comment: @Артем, на 10 секунд меня опередили)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте иначе задать кодировку для WebView:

```
myWeb.loadData(fullHtml, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```